# AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'titleBar'

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have written an GUI with tkinter. In the background I have to perfom some intensive calculations. From time to time I want to write some information from the calculation thread to the GUI window.

First I thought it was a good idea to add the computation code into the "mainloop". But this doesn't work, because the mainloop is resposible for keeping the GUI reactive. It seams to be no good idea to mainpulate it.

Below I have created a dummy app that scatches my new idea. The Sample app has a container. Inside that container, there is a TitleBar. The class TitleBar is defined below. It contains only one label.

Next I define a simple thread. It simulates a timeconsuming computation that wants to write some information to the GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # initialize the main window
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # add a container which will take all the widgets
        container = tk.Frame(self, bg="green")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # Add a titlebar object (defined below)
        titleBar = TitleBar(container, controller=self) 
        titleBar.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.E)


class TitleBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        # the title bar contains only one label element
        titleLabel = tk.Label(self, text="This is the initial text")
        titleLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


# Define a thread that runs in the background to perform intensive calculations
class MyTestThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            a = i+100        # intensive calculation

            # from time to time: inform use about status
            print(a)      # printing to console works fine
            app.titleBar.titleLabel['text'] = "test 1"   # --- FAILS ---


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()

    app.titleBar.titleLabel['text'] = "test 2"   # --- FAILS ---

    t = MyTestThread()
    t.start()

    app.mainloop()
```

The problem is that I cannot access the label to write information to it. The writing fails, both, from within the thread and from the app itself. In both cases it fails with the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'titleBar'
```

How can I access and change the properties of the label-object?

Thank you

Bernd

Comment: typo: titleBar is not an attribute of SampleApp and titleLabel in not an attribute of TitleBar , if you want it to be it changes: `titleBar = TitleBar(...` to `self.titleBar = TitleBar(...` and `titleLabel = tk.Label(...` to `self.titleLabel = tk.Label(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of eyllanesc and Mark_Bassem I was able to solve the problem. It seems that the problem was indeed very simple.

Just in case people will wisit this post in the future, I leave the correct code here:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # initialize the main window
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # add a container which will take all the widgets
        container = tk.Frame(self, bg="green")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # Add a titlebar object (defined below)
        self.titleBar = TitleBar(container, controller=self) 
        self.titleBar.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.E)


class TitleBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        # the title bar contains only one label element
        self.titleLabel = tk.Label(self, text="This is the initial text")
        self.titleLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


# Define a thread that runs in the background to perform intensive calculations
class MyTestThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            a = i+100        # intensive calculation

            # from time to time: inform use about status
            print(a)      # printing to console works fine
            app.titleBar.titleLabel['text'] = "status: " + str(a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()

    #app.titleBar.titleLabel['text'] = "test 2"

    t = MyTestThread()
    t.start()

    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `self` before the `titleBar` attribute